# Multiple Connected Hard Drive Permissions Not allowing rwx

Tags: permissions, hard-drive, files, disk

So I have multiple connected SATA drives in my PC.  Everytime I boot, I have to go through Nautilus and click on each one individually to get them to be recognized by the PC where then I can go through the terminal and explore the filesystem through `/media/$USER/name_of_connected_drives`.

`ls -alt`:

```
drwxrwxrwx connected_Drive_A
```

I've done both:

```
sudo chown -R $USER(my_name)/media/$USER/connected_Drive_A
sudo chmod 744 (and 755) -R /path_to_drive_A
```

The terminal runs through many files and states changing for drive with "read only permissions".

If I go through Nautilus and check the permissions in the GUI, it states that I (username) has full permissions of 'Create and delete files', yet I still cannot do anything with any of the drives except "read".

I've used the "disk" utility and edited mount options then back to default.  Mounted and unmounted the drives.  Restarted the computer multiple times.

I'm at a loss. I need to save things to the drives, but am at a wall. Hoping someone here has a clue what's going on with my computer.

Comment: You set ownership & permissions on partitions, not on drives. And then what format are those partitions, ext4 or NTFS? After mounting post these: `lsblk -f` and `cat /etc/fstab`  If internal drives best to mount with fstab. Are drives internal or external USB drives? Post this: `sudo lshw -C disk -short`

Comment: You are probably using an NTFS drive which does not understand Linux permissions.

Comment: https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld is a `bash` script to answer your Q